# CircleCI test failing due to an apparent merge conflict in /usr/local/lib/python3.6

Tags: python, git

I'm trying to push a commit, but our CircleCI yields the following puzzling error message:

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
cd lucy-web
source venv/bin/activate
python manage.py compilescss --verbosity 0
python manage.py collectstatic --clear --no-input --verbosity 0
python manage.py test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 29, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/root/lucy/lucy_web/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/root/lucy/lucy_web/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/root/lucy/lucy_web/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/root/lucy/lucy_web/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/root/lucy/lucy_web/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sass_processor/management/commands/compilescss.py", line 153, in handle
    self.parse_source(py_source)
  File "/root/lucy/lucy_web/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sass_processor/management/commands/compilescss.py", line 199, in parse_source
    tree = ast.parse(open(filename, 'rb').read())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ast.py", line 35, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 26
    <<<<<<< HEAD
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Exited with code 1
```

It seems like there are git merge conflicts in Python's `ast.py`. How might this have come about, and how can I fix it?

Comment: not `ast.py`, do `cd lucy_web; grep -r --include="*.py" -He '<<<< HEAD` to find files being affected

Comment: Oddly, `grep -r --include="*.py" -He '<<<< HEAD' .` yields several `./lucy-web/lucy_web/tests/test_feedback.py:<<<<<<< HEAD` lines as a result, but in my Atom Editor I can't actually see any such lines. How can this be?

Comment: `git branch -r` to show how many branches you have, `git status` to show how many uncommited, conflict files you have, `git log` to show who did what. the conflict can also be files other than `.py`. my guess you have already figured it out.